# DataTables+Symfony2 performance issue to deal with millions of data

Tags: php, symfony, datatables

I'm using Symfony2 along with DataTables, which works fine with max of 10,000 data records, but after that, it the page gets crashed or if i enable ajax with it, I get the JSON data mismatch or error in return.

Any idea how to handle millions of data with the help of DataTables AJAX/JSON?

Answer (score 1):

Millions of (client side) data won't work, even with modern browsers. Using a server side (AJAX) solution is the only way to go, but you'll have to paginate the results.

Using a bundle like [stwe/DatatablesBundle](https://github.com/stwe/DatatablesBundle) or [AliHichem/AliDatatableBundle](https://github.com/AliHichem/AliDatatableBundle) is a good start.